# How to append data option to niceSelect() jquery?. that code is not working if i use niceselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, select

```
$('#regencies').on('change', function(e){

    console.log(e);

    var regencies_id = e.target.value;
    $.get('/area/kec?regency_id=' + regencies_id,function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, districtsObj){
            $('#districts').append('<option value="'+ districtsObj.id +'">'+ districtsObj.name +'</option>');
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to update the select after adding new options:

```
$('#regencies').on('change', function(e) {
    var regencies_id = e.target.value;

    $.get('/area/kec?regency_id=' + regencies_id, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, districtsObj) {
            $('#districts').append('<option value="'+ districtsObj.id +'">'+ districtsObj.name +'</option>');
        });

        $('#districts').niceSelect('update');
    });
});
```

https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/